# get single row using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two row in a table such as:

| Code | Amount | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-08-02 16:47 |
| 1 | 105 | 2022-08-02 16:15 |
| 2 | 105 | 2022-08-02 16:15 |

I want max timestamp single row as output as:

| Code | Amount | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-08-02 16:47 |
| 2 | 105 | 2022-08-02 16:15 |

my code:

```sql
 select code, amount, max(timeStamp) from table 
group by code, amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you don't need aggregation functions, only this:

```
select top 1 code, amount, timeStamp from table order by timeStamp desc
```